# Google Smart Lock save dialog inaccessible in Android Oreo

Tags: c#, google-api, xamarin.android, android-8.0-oreo, google-smartlockpasswords

I know in 8.0, Autofill is preferred, but I want to force the Google Smart Lock save dialog. While implementing I get this error:

```
{Status{statusCode=The Credentials API's save confirmation dialog has been disabled to avoid conflicts with the Android Autofill feature. This choice may be overridden via AuthCredentialsOptions.Builder.forceEnableSaveDialog()., resolution=null}}
```

but in the Android [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/Auth.AuthCredentialsOptions.Builder), there is no method for this. No where in a Google search, or a search in the docs can I find this `forceEnableSaveDialog()` method.

Does anyone know how to force this dialog on 8.0 devices? I would like consistent behavior in my app across different versions.

Snippet of SaveCredentials code:

```
mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
                                                                       .AddConnectionCallbacks((obj) =>
                                                                       {
                                                                           var credendial = new Credential.Builder(userName).SetPassword(password).Build();

                                                                           Auth.CredentialsApi.Save(mCredentialsApiClient, credendial).SetResultCallback(new ResultCallback<IResult>((obj2) =>
                                                                           {
                                                                               Print("Saved");
                                                                                if (obj2.Status.IsSuccess)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    Print("Credentails successfully saved with Google Smart Lock");
                                                                                }
                                                                                else if (obj2.Status.StatusCode == CommonStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired)
                                                                                {  
                                                                                    obj2.Status.StartResolutionForResult(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, obj2.Status.StatusCode);
                                                                                }
                                                                           }));
                                                                       })
                                                                       .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(NotConnected)
                                                                       .AddApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                                                                       .Build();
                            mCredentialsApiClient.Connect();
```

This is Android in Xamarin. Same methods and everything, just using C#

Comment: Can you show me the code you currently have?

Comment: I added a snippet of code for where I save. the obj2.Status that's returned is where this message is coming from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "...there is no method for this. No where in a Google search, or a search in the docs can I find this forceEnableSaveDialog() method."

This is due to the window between when a version of the Google Play services APK and its corresponding client library is released (Overview of the structure [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview)).

In the corresponding client release `AuthCredentialOptions.forceEnableSaveDialog()` will be available along with documentation covering its use. I will update this question once it is available, but you can also watch release notes [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

**Update 1:** The corresponding Google Play Services client library has been released. The [overview documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/package-summary#targeting-android-o-and-above)'s "Targeting Android O and above" section has more details on this.

**Update 2:** In latest version (Version 11.8.0) `AuthCredentialOptions` has been deprecated, replaced by the new [`CredentialOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/CredentialsOptions).

Comment: AuthCredentialOptions.Builder object is missing the build() method.

Answer (score 1):

The method was missing from the public SDK for AuthCredentialsOptions.Builder and we fixed it (see the accepted answer)

**But a more important clarification: Autofill with Google save dialog stores passwords to the same Smart Lock database**, so if the Autofill dialog shows, then you don't need to worry about using the API to force the other dialog to show (in fact, if you force the dialog via the API, then make sure to suppress the Autofill one ... user should not see two dialogs). Data saved via either dialog will be available for Smart Lock auto sign-in (and vice versa for Autofill) and the data is sync'ed via Google Account with Chrome (autofill and API).

Since the dialogs store data to the same place, we opted to show the Autofill with Google one when user uses Google as their autofill manager because it will provide a consistent experience across all apps on Oreo devices. Working on improving error message, documentation, and branding to clarify this. Sorry for the confusion.